# How to reorder contact info in Contacts.app

Tags: contacts

I'm a hoarder of contact info in Contacts.app.  I always keep people's old contact info in their Contacts.app entry so that, for example, their pic will show up in Mail.app on even old emails from them.

This leads to a lot of contact info building up, and I would like to reorder such contact info so that older ones are lower on the list.  There doesn't seem to be an in-app way to do this, outside of manually putting everything in again in the order that you want them. That is particularly annoying because I'd like the newest contact info at the top and each time anyone changes anything I'd have to redo the order, and also it's not feasible to implement it over a large contact database, which I have.

So:

1. Is there actually an *easy* in-app way to do this?
2. If not, is there any third-party product that will do this?
3. If not, is there a way that I can just go into the Address Book database and do this?

Comment: That would depend on what information you have in your contacts to sort on.

Comment: I think I will need to sort manually.  It would be awesome if, for example, I could sort emails by the last date I received an email from that address in Mail.app, but I'll be content if I can quickly reorder things manually for people I'm in regular contact with.

Comment: Are we talking about the contacts in the Address Book, or about emails sorting?

Comment: Sorry, typo in the last comment; it should read "I could sort *contacts' emails* by the last date I received an email…" Just to be clear, we are talking about sorting contact info within a contact within Contacts.app.  For example, a given contact might have 10 emails.  I'd like an easy way to put those emails in my preferred order.

Comment: ok got it, thanks, looking for a possible solution :)

Comment: I found something close to what you want "The contact list is sorted by the date of the last email".

Comment: That sounds like it's higher up in the hierarchy than I need to be. The hierarchy is (1) Contacts.app > (2) contacts > (3) contact info.  If my understanding is correct, that's sorting at (2) while I'm aiming to reorder in (3).

Comment: I said closest :) your need to modify would require to export the addressbook.abbu file to CSV format and then some more ! are you up to that ?

Comment: Wouldn't exporting to CSV cause a loss of certain data, e.g., the contact's photo?

Comment: Yes, but you can also export as VCF (vCard), then edit the `Email` field in there - just open the vCard or vcf file with a text editor.

Answer (score 3):

**Export Contacts:**

Export your contacts to a VCF (vCard) file. You can do this by selecting all your contacts (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and then choosing **File** > **Export** > **Export vCard.**
This will create a VCF file with all your contacts.

**Edit the VCF File:**

Open the exported VCF file using a text editor (like TextEdit).
In the VCF file, each contact is represented by a series of lines starting with `BEGIN:VCARD` and ending with `END:VCARD`.

You can reorder the contact entries in the VCF file based on your preference. Move the contact entries to reorder them.

**Import the Edited VCF File:**

Save the edited VCF file.
Go back to the Contacts app.
Choose **File** > **Import** and select the edited VCF file.

This method essentially involves manually reordering the entries in the VCF file and then re-importing them. While this is not an ideal solution, it might be a workaround for your specific situation.